# Create a column counting number of consecutive negative days

Tags: pandas, dataframe, iteration, cumsum

I have huge (more than 3 million rows) pandas dataframe containing the following data:

```
companyId     dateBalance       amount 
    1          2020-04-17         100     
    1          2020-04-18          40       
    1          2020-04-19          20       
    1          2020-04-20         -40       
    1          2020-04-21          30       
    2          2020-04-18           5       
    2          2020-04-19           1       
    2          2020-04-20          -6       
    2          2020-04-21          -60      
    2          2020-04-22          200
```

I would like to create a new column that counts the number of days in a row the company is with negative balance, so for this case, we have the following

```
companyId     dateBalance       amount  negCount
    1          2020-04-17         100       0
    1          2020-04-18          40       0
    1          2020-04-19          20       0
    1          2020-04-20         -40       1
    1          2020-04-21          30       0
    2          2020-04-18           5       0
    2          2020-04-19           1       0
    2          2020-04-20          -6       1
    2          2020-04-21          -60      2 
    2          2020-04-22          200      0
```

Is there a quick way of doing this (i.e., some way that does not require iteration over every line)? Note that the index must "reset" every sign change and for every different company as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `groupby().cumsum()` on the negation of the criteria to identify the blocks, then groupby the blocks again:

```
blocks = df['amount'].ge(0).groupby(df['companyId']).cumsum()
df['negCount'] = df.groupby([df['companyId'],blocks]).cumcount()
```

Output:

```
   companyId dateBalance  amount  negCount
0          1  2020-04-17     100         0
1          1  2020-04-18      40         0
2          1  2020-04-19      20         0
3          1  2020-04-20     -40         1
4          1  2020-04-21      30         0
5          2  2020-04-18       5         0
6          2  2020-04-19       1         0
7          2  2020-04-20      -6         1
8          2  2020-04-21     -60         2
9          2  2020-04-22     200         0
```